# Import bulk email addresses

Tags: civimail

I have 700 email addresses in an Excel doc. How can I import them en masse to a single smart folder for a one-off mailing?

Comment: Phillip - we are all volunteering here to help each other out. it would be polite to at least acknowledge that someone has tried to help you by providing an Answer

Answer (score 1):

When you import you can specify 'add to group' or 'add to new group' on the final step of the import wizard

It doesn't make sense to me why this should be a 'smart group' per your OP ah but you said 'smart folder'. shrug. hope my answer helps :-)